# How do I get IntelliJ's GUI builder to set component names

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Is there a way to get the IntelliJ GUI builder to set Swing component name properties?

In NetBeans, I can do this by selecting the "Set Component Names" property on the form itself (not the JFrame, but the actual top-level form item in the Navigator).  I can't find a similar option in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of the component manually by enabling *Show expert properties* and editing the *name* property. As far as I know there is no way to automatically set the name of the component.

Comment: Unfortunately there does not seem to be the possibility to use a constant as a name, either.